# Puppeteer `page` object not working after `page.goto` timed out?

Tags: puppeteer

I ran the following code many times, `page.goto` mostly timed out and then the later part of the code (starting at NOTE) is never successfully executed at all, i.e. I cannot see `contentSize = ...` printed to console.

But if `page.goto` didn't time out, then I can see `contentSize = ...` printed.

So `page` object cannot work properly if `.goto` times out?

```js
import pptr from "puppeteer";  // version = 10.1.0

async function main(args) {
    let browser = await pptr.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [
            "--user-data-dir=/tmp/user_data/",
            "--window-size=1200,1080",
        ]
    });

    const url = "https://venturebeat.com/";
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 10000 })
      .catch(err => console.log(`page.goto rejected, err: ${err}`)),
    console.log(`stop loading`);

    // NOTE: seems stuck here forever?
    let contentSize = (await page.content()).length;
    console.log(`content size = ${contentSize}`);

};

main();
```

After adding many `console.log` in the puppeeter source code, seems like it's actually stuck at [the code here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/859135adb638a5c30e468718173d25b3ed4c0fba/src/common/ExecutionContext.ts#L270-L271).

UPDATE: strangely after I switch from Chromium to Chrome, the issue seems gone.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce other than setting the timeout really short, like 800 ms, I can get a `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.` if I try `page.content()` after the catch, but I assume that's not your problem. Can you share a [mcve], probably with a live URL or text contents that causes the failure? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be better to `await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded " });` + `await page.waitForTimeout(10000)`?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty What is the difference from what I've coded?

Comment: This variant does not throw timeout error. Maybe it will not hung just because of that?

Comment: @avocado After the update, it still worked fine for me. I get `content size = 380208`. After that, yeah, the process hangs because `await browser.close()` is never called but that's probably not what you're asking about.

Comment: @ggorlen Actually for me, the updated code sometimes work, and mostly not, no idea why not always work, driving me crazy.

Comment: @ggorlen What? You mean I need to close the Page or Browser explicitly every time?

Comment: Yeah, the process won't exit until you close the browser.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry I think there are some misunderstanding between us, since I don't think I need to close the Browser explicitly in the code, this is not a problem in my post, the problem is I cannot even get `content size = ...` printed at all, which means the code execution never successfully gets the contentSize at all, hence it is stuck there.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Well, I ran it 3 times locally and got content size printed and a clean exit, so I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem. Nothing in your code looks unusual other than catching the `goto`. Maybe try updating Puppeteer or see if you can reproduce the problem without catching the `goto` -- set a really high timeout, because the `goto` throw might be a red herring. You could also try some other call than `page.content()` to see if that works, or try a different system (I used Windows when I ran your code). Maybe also try removing `"--user-data-dir=/tmp/user_data/",`.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks so much for testing the code!!
High timeout might not be an option for me, since I intentionally just want to wait for 10s, otherwise stop waiting/loading.
Could you please tell your puppeteer version? I'm using 10.1.0

Comment: Originally `"puppeteer": "^8.0.0"`, but I just upgraded to 10.1.0 and it still worked. The high timeout time is just a debugging tool to establish that it really is the throw/catch on the goto that's causing the problem. If you let the page fully load, and `page.content()` works and your script exits, then you've localized the problem. If you still get the same hang, then you know that catching `goto` throwing probably wasn't the problem as you thought (I suspect that the latter will be the case, I doubt the `goto` catch is causing a problem here).